# Is there any applications for short data transmission?

Tags: communication, modulation, transmitter, power-amplifier

In some applications like IoT,

the transmitter turns off for power saving when the transmission is not needed.

I'm not sure but I heard that:

when the transmitter is on, the **data length - in time - tends to be us(or ms) length @ 2.4GHz.**

Just for my curiosity,
**is there any other applications whose data length - in time - tends to be sub-us(ns) length?**
(regardless of the frequency of carrier)

Comment: I expect there are but it will be at high carrier frequencies.

Comment: Radar pulses?..

Comment: If your data rate is (say) 100Mbps then that's 10ns per bit. That means you can send up to 99 bits - including the preamble - without going over 1us. Is that useful? Maybe, but probably not.